# Qt, c++ QML and HWND

Tags: c++, qt, qml, hwnd

I need to use a DLL -library that requests a window handle (HWND) to draw it self on a form.
I don't want it to ocupy the whole main form but be displayed in for example a sub widget's area.
Now this is no problem using windows forms. But Can I do it using Qt or even with a Qt QML based ui?
Let's say I have a mainwindow and want this library to draw itself on a QML rectangle inside the main window. can i provide the library with a valid handle in any way?
this post is related but does not solve anything : [DevNet HWND in QML](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/4106)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible, I did it some days ago in a project.

You can retrieve the win ID of any widget, thanks to : [QWidget::winId](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qwidget.html#winId).

I didn't try with QML, but as QML is drawn in a QGraphicsView( which is a QWidget ), maybe that can work.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense.As the qlm stuff is inside a QGraphicsScene I doupt that any of the qml components can give me a window handle.I guess the best way is to base the ui on widgets and put in qml where I need it.

Comment: I think you well understood the philosophy of QT4, for a lot of desktop application, you can build all the application without doing QML. In QT4 QML is very interesting if you want to do a modern "look n feel" application. In QT5, that will be different, I think QML will be used every time (but old QWidget will also exists in QT5)

Comment: Yes, QT5 was the main reason for me asking this question. If basing UIs on QML and not widgets is the future, then this might not be so easy.

Comment: True, but QML components will be in some QGraphicsView, so if your QT5 Ui have a widget drawn by another Win32 native library, you will build your UI in QT creator with some empty widget (to be filled by your native library), some empty QGraphicsView (which will be filled with a QT Quick Ui in QML), and why not, some QT4 QWidget.